# FSharp.Core FSharpFunc.FromConverter in netstandard20

Tags: f#, .net-standard-2.0

In converting a project to .NET Standard 2.0, `FSharpFunc<T, TResult>`. `FromConverter` method from the `FSharp.Core` library is not available anymore. Is there a way to convert this code to a .NET Standard 2.0 `FSharp.Core` implementation?

```
async Task<Unit> RunProcess(FSharpMailboxProcessor<T> mailbox, Func<T, Task> process) { ... }

public BaseMailboxProcessor(Func<TFuncInput, Task> process, Action<Exception, TFuncInput> errorHandler = null, CancellationToken? cancellationToken = null)
{
    m_ErrorHandler = errorHandler;
    m_TokenSource = cancellationToken.HasValue ? CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken.Value) :
                                                 new CancellationTokenSource();
    var cancellationOption = FSharpOption<CancellationToken>.Some(m_TokenSource.Token);
    Converter<FSharpMailboxProcessor<TMailboxInput>, FSharpAsync<Unit>> converter = (mailbox) =>
    {
        return FSharpAsync.AwaitTask<Unit>(RunProcess(mailbox, process));
    };

    m_Mailbox = new FSharpMailboxProcessor<TMailboxInput>(FSharpFunc<FSharpMailboxProcessor<TMailboxInput>, FSharpAsync<Unit>>.FromConverter(converter), cancellationOption);
    m_Mailbox.Start();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use `FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc`, this appears to still be present in the netstandard version of FSharp.Core.

Comment: The problem with `FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc` is that it returns `FSharpFunc<T, Unit>` and I need it to return `FSharpFunc<FSharpMailboxProcessor<TMailboxInput>, FSharpAsync<Unit>>`, where T is `FSharpMailboxProcessor<TMailboxInput>` unless I am missing something that isn't possible with that method.

Comment: There are two overloads of `FuncConvert.ToFSharpFunc`, one for `Action<T>` and one for `Converter<T, TResult>`.  The overload for `Converter<T, TResult>` should be exactly what you need.

Comment: I should have specified this but I am on the latest of FSharp.Core which is 4.4.1.0. The method is not available in that version for netstandard20, but is available in 4.4.0.0.

Comment: I've also checked and `ToFSharpFunc` doesn't appear when using .net standard 2.0. Not sure why though.

Answer (score 1):

You can trivially define your own:

```
let ToFSharpFunc (converter: System.Func<_, _>) = fun t -> converter.Invoke t
```

Also, if you need to use an `FSharpFunc` in C# you can simply call `.Invoke` on it where `.Invoke` on the `FSharpFunc` object is a `Func`.

Comment: I was hoping for a C# implementation. However, as a last resort including an F# dll with this function could work.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do `.Invoke` on the `FSharpFunc` when you use it in C#?